# How do I fill a symbolic N-dim zero array in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, sympy, symbols, numpy-ndarray

I've initialized the following array:

```
ChristSymb=sym.Array(np.zeros((d,d,d),dtype=int))
```

and I've been trying to fill it up with symbolic expressions using a for loop, but after compiling appear the following error

```
TypeError: immutable N-dim array
```

What's wrong with the array definition that cannot be modified? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `sym.Array` is actually an abbreviation for `ImmutableDenseNDimArray`. This information is available in the [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/tensor/array.html). What you need to do is use the mutable version class called `MutableDenseNDimArray` like this:

```py
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np

ChristSymb = sym.MutableDenseNDimArray(np.zeros((d, d, d), dtype=int))
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array` is an abbrevation for `ImmutableDenseNDimArray`. *Immutable* means that its component elements cannot be changed once the array is defined.

You can create a mutable array of zeros with one of these ways:

```
In [2]: MutableDenseNDimArray.zeros(3,3,3)
Out[2]: [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```

This creates a mutable array of zeros (note that you don't need *NumPy*, as *SymPy* also has the *zeros(...)* function).

Otherwise, convert the immutable array to a mutable array:

```
In [3]: Array.zeros(3,3,3).as_mutable()
Out[3]: [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]
```